# How to interchange the html div elements position using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
```

How do I interchange the position of Div's using Javascript ? and it should be changed in HTML Document also ?

like :

```
<div>7</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>1</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>3</div>
```

It should be changed like this and should save in HTML document also

Comment: why do you want to change the position of `div`

Comment: I was working on a puzzle game when i click on the button puzzle need to split into different positions so that we can solve the puzzle

Comment: Using destructing, it could be more simple. Check my answer @ram-sai

Answer (score 1):

You can swap two array elements by using `[a, b] = [b, a]` technique.

```js
const divs = [...document.querySelectorAll('div')];
[divs[1], divs[3]] = [divs[3], divs[1]]

divs.forEach(el => document.body.appendChild(el));
```

```html
<div id="1">1</div>
<div id="2">2</div>
<div id="3">3</div>
<div id="4">4</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't change the DOM elements just elements in an array

Comment: I've generated the modified array. Now anyone can loop through it and append the element to a common parent.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the easiest way to sort out the issue.
Think of external div's / nodes as containers or places inside where the content will be replaced. (you don't have to replace the divs but you will have to replace their content.)

```js
function replaceContent(x, z){
  // save the inner html of the first node in temp
  let temp = document.getElementById(x).innerHTML;
  // move the innerHtml of the second node into first node
  document.getElementById(x).innerHTML = document.getElementById(z).innerHTML;
  // replace the second node's inner html with temp (saved previously)
  document.getElementById(z).innerHTML = temp;
}

// replace the divs of id 2 and 4
replaceContent("2", "4");
```

```html
<div id="1">1</div>
<div id="2">2</div>
<div id="3">3</div>
<div id="4">4</div>
```

Comment: Bro if we interchange using javascript it is interchanged in html also even after refreshing page ?

Comment: no the change is temporary as the function is only manipulating the dom. if you want it to change on refresh even then you will need server side scripting to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const parent = document.querySelector(".parent");
const children = [...parent.children];
[children[1].innerHTML, children[3].innerHTML] = [
  children[3].innerHTML,
  children[1].innerHTML
];
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div>1</div>
   <div>2</div>
   <div>3</div>
   <div>4</div>
</div>
```